# How to install \ Import the ebay sdk

Tags: java, android, ebay-sdk

So I'm trying to install / import the ebay SDK for java in Eclipse, but I can't it's in some strange file I don't know about, I need to do this so I can execute the getMyEbayBuyings call, described here: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/908/kw/ebay%20getMyebayBuying

(Or at least try to...)

Can anyone help me out with importing the ebay sdk to eclipse so I can start with that?
Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: Download the version you need from here:
https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools/sdks/java http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/javasdk-jaxb/docs/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html Go to the section "Installing the SDK" -> "To Install the Java SDK for Eclipse" I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After you download the sdk, you want to add the jar files in the sdk to your project path. In eclipse, right click on your project, then click properties -> java build path -> libraries. Then click "add external JARs...", and navigate to the downloaded sdk file. Select all the jars you want to import, then you should be able to import the things you want.